# Elm 0.17: HTTP request on init

Tags: elm

I have followed [this blog post](https://medium.com/@diamondgfx/writing-a-full-site-in-phoenix-and-elm-a4622c5130f5#.f8wa4r2eu) to make an HTTP call when I click a button. I would like to load that data on `init`, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39967330/elm-http-request-on-init) asks, but the solutions given there aren't clear enough for me and my slightly different code.

The **app update and init** code:

```
init : (Model, Cmd Msg)
init =
  ( initialModel, Cmd.none )

-- UPDATE

type Msg
  = ArticleListMsg ArticleList.Msg

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
  case msg of
    ArticleListMsg articleMsg ->
      let (updatedModel, cmd) = ArticleList.update articleMsg model.articleListModel
      in ( { model | articleListModel = updatedModel }, Cmd.map ArticleListMsg cmd )
```

The **ArticleList update** code:

```
module ArticleList exposing (..)

-- UPDATE

type Msg
  = NoOp
  | Fetch
  | FetchSucceed (List Article.Model)
  | FetchFail Http.Error

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
  case msg of
    NoOp ->
      (model, Cmd.none)
    Fetch ->
      (model, fetchArticles)
    FetchSucceed articleList ->
      (Model articleList, Cmd.none)
    FetchFail error ->
      case error of
        Http.UnexpectedPayload errorMessage ->
          Debug.log errorMessage
          (model, Cmd.none)
        _ ->
          (model, Cmd.none)

-- HTTP calls

fetchArticles : Cmd Msg
fetchArticles =
  let
    url = "/api/articles"
  in
    Task.perform FetchFail FetchSucceed (Http.get decodeArticleFetch url)
```

I've tried sending the command on `init` instead of `Cmd.none`:

```
init : (Model, Cmd Msg)
init =
  ( initialModel, ArticleList.Fetch )
```

But the compiler complains:

```
The type annotation is saying:

( Model, Cmd Msg )

But I am inferring that the definition has this type:

( Model, ArticleList.Msg )
```

I've also tried passing the function:

```
init =
  ( initialModel, ArticleList.fetchArticles )
```

But the compiler complains:

```
Cannot find variable `ArticleList.fetchArticles`.

30|   ( initialModel, ArticleList.fetchArticles )
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
`ArticleList` does not expose `fetchArticles`.
```

How can I send the correct message to make the HTTP call on init?

Comment: Maybe look at this simplified example https://github.com/rofrol/elm-route-url/blob/simplify/examples/elm-architecture-tutorial/MainWithFullUrl.elm

Comment: This is code from 0.17. The Http module had a lot of breaking changes.

Comment: You put your initial Http call in the init's `Cmd` part of the `( Model, Cmd Msg )` rather than having `Cmd.none`. So `init = ( initModel, fetchArticles )`?

Comment: @rofrol thanks for that. I looked through it, but it doesn't seem to answer my question. I've udpated my question with the code I thought should work, and the compiler error, if you have any other ideas.

Comment: You don't need the `Fetch` if you're opening with the Cmd. [Here](https://github.com/toastal/elm-applicatives-and-json-decoders/blob/d7a3063489985c18d669babf27226e63602ed35e/demo/PokemonViewer.elm) is a single-file complete Elm app I wrote at the 0.17 commit with an initial fetch.

Comment: @toastal So I tried to replace `Cmd.none` with the `ArticleList.fetchArticles` function. That seems to be what your code indicates? Anyway, it's not working, but I've opened a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386891/elm-0-17-module-does-not-expose-function) because it seems like a different issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `init` should be

```elm
init : (Model, Cmd Msg)
init =
  ( initialModel, Cmd.map ArticleListMsg ArticleList.fetchArticles )
```

`ArticleList.fetchArticles` has type `Cmd ArticleList.Msg`. You need to use [`Cmd.map`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Platform-Cmd#map) to map that value to type `Cmd Msg` using the `ArticleListMsg` type constructor.